# Position fixed element which is stopped scrolling beyond footer, jitters while stopping

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I was trying to stop my rightside element which has fixed position, from scrolling beyond the footer i was successful but now i am facing new issue, although the element stops at footer it jumps while stopping/scrolling.
I tried applying css transition but still not successful, below is my partial code,

```
<div class="rightside_content">
<a id="" href="">
    <img src="https://dabuttonfactory.com/button.png?t=Your+text+here&f=Calibri-Bold&ts=24&tc=fff&tshs=1&tshc=000&hp=20&vp=8&c=5&bgt=gradient&bgc=3d85c6&ebgc=073763">
</a>
<a id="" href="">
    <img src="https://dabuttonfactory.com/button.png?t=Your+text+here&f=Calibri-Bold&ts=24&tc=fff&tshs=1&tshc=000&hp=20&vp=8&c=5&bgt=gradient&bgc=3d85c6&ebgc=073763">
</a>
```

```
<footer class="main_footer">
</footer>

<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .rightside_content {
        position: fixed;
        right: 5%;
        width: 22%;
        margin-top: 0;
         /* -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease; */
        /* -moz-transition: position 15s; */
        /* -ms-transition: position 15s; */
        /* -o-transition: position 15s; */
        /* transition: all 0.15s ease; */
        /* animation: smoothScroll 1s forwards; */
    }
}
</style>

<script>
$(window).scroll(() => {
    var footerToTop = $('.main_footer').offset().top;
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var difference = scrollTop - footerToTop;
    var bottomValue = scrollTop > footerToTop ? difference : "inherit";
    $('.rightside_content').css("bottom",bottomValue);
});
</script>
```

Can this issue be handled from jquery only?

Comment: can you add a reproducible code snippet? that would help

Comment: Read this article on animation performance, it might stop the stuttering: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/